# Conversion of SQL to Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Below are my django models

```
class SourceFile(models.Model):
    full_path = models.TextField(unique = False)
    project_name = models.TextField(blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_path

class Coverage(models.Model):
    line_pct = models.IntegerField(default = 0, blank = True)
    source_file = models.ForeignKey(SourceFile, related_name = 'coverage', null = True)
    date_generated = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now, blank = True)
    def source_file_full_path(self):
        return self.source_file.full_path
```

Now i want count of distinct id of source file table present in coverage table based on project_name.
I wrote a sql query for the same but unable to write django equivalent for the same.

```
select count(distinct(sf.id)), sf.project_name from coverage c inner join sourcefile sf on c.source_file_id = sf.id group by sf.project_name;
```

Please help with this

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

You can use raw sql in django but it is much easier to use django manager.

I'm sorry I can't provide more specific help but I am not entirely sure what exactly you need.